# cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function - Redux Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux

Hey guys I got a problem with my react-redux setup,
I'm using redux toolkit,

While searching I've seen some solutions however they don't fit my need since the async call is being
made outside the UseEffect Function.
Why is even a call being made again when I switch to another page I don't get it

My Code:

```
import React, { useState,useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { query, currToy,CurrToys } from './toySlice';

export function ToyApp() {
  
  const toysFromDb=useSelector(CurrToys)
  const[localStateToys,setToys]=useState([])
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const mountedRef = useRef(true)
  
  
  useEffect(() => { 
       dispatch(query()).then(data=>{
         setToys(toysFromDb)
       })
      }, [localStateToys])

    return (
        <div>
            {localStateToys.map(toy=>{
              return(<article key={toy._id}>
                <li>{toy.name}</li>
              </article>)
            })}
   
        </div>
    )
}
```

The Slice:

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";
const baseUrl = '/api/toys';

export const query = createAsyncThunk('loadToys', () =>
    axios.get(baseUrl)
   .then(ok => ok.data)
   .catch(err => err),
);



export const toySlice = createSlice({
    name: 'toysServices',
    initialState: {
        toys:[],
        currToy:null
    },
    reducers: {
        test: (state, action) => {
            console.log('In Test')
        },
       
    },
    extraReducers: {
        [query.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
            state.toys = action.payload
        }
    }
});

export const { test } = toySlice.actions;

export const CurrToys = state => state.toyReducer.toys;
export const currToy = state => state.toyReducer.currToy;

export default toySlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can define `cleanup` for that. Like this.

```
useEffect(() => {
    let isOut = false
    dispatch(query()).then(data => {
        if (!isOut) {
            setToys(toysFromDb)
        }
    })
    return () => {
        isOut = true
    }
}, [localStateToys])
```

The problem seems to be that `setToys` is called when the component is already unmounted.

For more details about cleanup, you can visit their [official site](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)